# "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key the duplicate key value is 0."

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm getting this error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

but I don't know how to resolve it.

I'm trying to write a blackjack game and have the user enter usernames and passwords etc but I'm not the best at coding and I'm struggling in finding what I would need to do to be able to actually make it store the data in the database without the error message coming up

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace NEATechnicalSolution
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        databasecontrol sql = new databasecontrol();

        void register()
        {
            sql.Params("@Username", UNtxtBox.Text);
            sql.Params("@Password", PasswordtxtBox.Text);
            sql.Params("@Email", EAtxtBox.Text);
            sql.Params("@FirstName", FNtxtBox.Text);
            sql.Params("@Surname", SNtxtBox.Text);
            sql.Params("@DOB", DOBtxtBox.Text);
            sql.Params("@Mnumber", IDtxtBox.Text);
            sql.query("INSERT into Tbl_registration(Username, Password, Email, FirstName, Surname, DOB, Mnumber)" + "VALUES(@Username, @Password, @Email, @FirstName, @Surname, @DOB, @Mnumber)");
            
            if (sql.ErrorChecking(true)) 
            {
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Registered||| Welcome To Blackjack");
        }

        private void BtnRegistered_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new Login();
            myForm.Show();
            Close();

            register();
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a primary key setup in the db and you are trying to insert a row with a pk that already exists.

Comment: Whenever i enter anything different the same error message comes up

Comment: Primary Keys can either be automatic or manual.  Most prefer them to be automatically created by the db itself. Is @Mnumber the primary key?

Comment: yes it is, would you say mine is manual

Comment: can you post you're table schema?

Comment: looks like passing text to `@Mnumber` parameter causes `@Mnumber` to be interpreted as 0. Try with `int.Parse(IDtxtBox.Text)` as `@Mnumber` param value

Comment: what is a table schema

Comment: @Nino this didn't work, it said "input string was not in the correct format"

Comment: There isnt enough info to help you out here.  Please provide more info.

Comment: what else do you need to see

Comment: comment out line sql.Params("@Mnumber", IDtxtBox.Text); - and delete Mnumber in query - what happens